# sort numbers with corresponding string in descending order

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

I have a list

```
codelist=['11CE711-141', '11CS710-142', '11EC710-142', '11EE610-8', '11EEP60-5', '11IT610-1', '11ITRA0-66', '11ME710-141', '11MT710-71']
```

I want to sorted list in descending order based on numerical value looks like below

```
codelist=['11CS710-142','11EC710-142','11CE711-141','11ME710-141','11MT710-71','11ITRA0-66','11EE610-8','11EEP60-5','11IT610-1']
```

Kindly suggest me ideas to resolve this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort with a key function that returns the second token after splitting with `-` and converting the token to an integer:

```
sorted(codelist, key=lambda s: -int(s.split('-')[1]))
```

Comment: Great.This code is working fine. I was trying to do it using string compare with two arrays and for loops to compare the swap content which is more than 10 lines but this one line code did all correctly without any hassle .Great help and timely response.Thanks a lot! You made my day better.